# How to find other textbox ID in textboxchanged event?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am Using **VB**. The logic is simple, but I cant find the control ID. I have a gridview, when I click the Edit button, I can edit this row, right? there are 3 textboxes named quantity, unit_cost and total. That means these 3 textbox is in **EditTemplate**. When I change the quantity textbox's value, the total textbox's value should be updated. But the issue is I can find total textbox ID in quantity_textchanged. **How to update the total, when user change the quantity** ? Thank you so much for your help.

```
Protected Sub quantity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim quantity As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim ContainerValue As String = quantity.Text.Trim

End Sub

<asp:TemplateField >
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbContainers" runat="server" Text="No. of Containers"    CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="NUMBER_OF_CONTAINERS">
</asp:Label><br/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtContainer" runat="server"  Width="90px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtContainer_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
</HeaderTemplate>    
<EditItemTemplate> 
<asp:TextBox ID="quantity"  Width="100px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NUMBER_OF_CONTAINERS") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="quantity_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox> 
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblContainers" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NUMBER_OF_CONTAINERS")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you tried with Javascript?

Comment: show your gridview's relevant markup

Comment: <EditItemTemplate> 
<asp:TextBox ID="quantity"  Width="100px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NUMBER_OF_CONTAINERS") %>' AutoPostBack="true"  OnTextChanged="quantity_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox> 
</EditItemTemplate>

Comment: no you can't edit it.  your gridview edittemplate is missing 2 of the 3 textboxes you say you have, where are they? i see quantity...where are unit_cost and total?

Comment: I have 2 and 3 textboxes, I did not paste them here. I sure have. They are the same as 1 textbox except the ID and other stuff

Comment: You are not providing near enough information for the community to provide a meaningful answer.  But if all you want to do is calculate a new total then just allow the user to update the quantity and unit_cost.  When the user selects update, save those two fields back to the datastore.  the Total field should not be an editable field, but a calculated field from your sql statement or calculated in the gridview RowDataBound event.